# how to give permissions to specific user "A" in regedit With regini.exe

Tags: windows-7, permissions, user-accounts, window, regedit

how to give permissions to specific user "A" in **regedit** With **regini.exe**.
I found material microsoft but did not help me

for example :

*User:* A

*PATH:* HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes

**Links:**

https://web.archive.org/web/20150314213933/http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/237607

https://web.archive.org/web/20150215035614/https://support.microsoft.com/kb/142265

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regini supports only those predefined account/groups listed in the Microsoft article. Better way to assign permissions is by using Microsoft's [SubInACL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=23510), or 3rd party [SetACL](https://helgeklein.com/setacl/).